# What happens when you have highly correlated columns in a dataset?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, correlation, pca

I am doing a `regression model`. And I was wondering what would be the consequence if we have two or more `Highly correlated` columns in the dataset? Is that something that can decrease the accuracy of the model?

Answering this question would help decide how to deal with it. Would `PCA` be the best option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having highly correlated features is a type of redundancy in features. And yes, it effects a regression model if you are having highly correlated features. A very nice explanation is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/what-is-the-effect-of-having-correlated-predictors-in-a-multiple-regression-mode).

PCA is a nice choice when it comes to dimensionality reduction.